# Themida devirtualization?

Tags: ida, virtualizers

I'm trying to analyze virtualized? code in IDA which looks like this.
[image]

[image]

which protection method is applyed on this code and how can i analyze this code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. You're aware that Themida offers a range of VMs, right? I checked on Themida 3.1.2.60 and counted 42 public VMs. You can, however, also define your own. And then any combination of these can be used to "treat" an executable.